# Cannot read property 'top' of undefined in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just developed a website with scrolling effect using jQuery. When I'm clicking on the menu item, it should scroll down and display the section. When I click on the particular menu, it scrolls down. But in the url, I'm getting `www.example.com/#menuitem_name`. The particular section is not active.

This is my jQuery file:

```
$('body').scrollspy({
    target: '.navbar-fixed-top',
    offset: 80
})

$('a.page-scroll').bind('click', function(event) {
    var link = $(this);
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: $(link.attr('href')).offset().top - 70
    }, 500);
    event.preventDefault();
});

});
```

HTML

```
<section id="beta1.0" class="container">Hi</section>
<li><a class="page-scroll" href="#beta1.0">Beta1.0</a> hi</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your selector looks like this: `#beta1.0`

That means "An element with the *id* `beta` and the *class* `0`" (or would if you could have a `0` immediately after a `.` in a selector).

You need to escape the `.`.

```
link.attr('href').replace(".", "\\.", "g")
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Quentin answer.

It is causing problem because of beta1.0
If You just remove .0 or just dot. it works fine.

**[Find jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/locateganesh/dexh5dkb/)**

```
$(function(){
/*
$('body').scrollspy({
    target: '.navbar-fixed-top',
    offset: 80
});
*/

$('a.page-scroll').bind('click', function(event) {
    var link = $(this);
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: $(link.attr('href')).offset().top - 70
    }, 500);
    event.preventDefault();
});

});
```